# Bounding the function $(-z)^{s-1}$ over the square with vertices $(\pm(2n+1) \pi,\pm(2n+1) \pi)$

Tags: complex-analysis, inequality

In Ahlfors' Complex analysis text, page 216 he claims that $\left \lvert (-z)^{s-1} \right \rvert$ is bounded by a *multiple* of $n^{\sigma+1}$ over the square contour $C_n'$ with vertices in $$(\pm(2n+1) \pi,\pm(2n+1) \pi) .$$
Here $s=\sigma+it$, and the complex power is defined via the principal branch, where $-\pi<\Im \log(-z)<\pi$.

I'm not sure what the author means by a *multiple*, but here is my attempt:

$\left \lvert (-z)^{s-1} \right \rvert=\left \lvert e^{(s-1) \log(-z)} \right \rvert=\left \lvert e^{(\sigma+it-1) [\ln|z|+i \arg(-z)]} \right \rvert= e^{\Re \{ (\sigma-1+it) [\ln|z|+i \arg(-z)] \} }=e^{(\sigma-1) \ln |z|-t \arg(-z)}=|z|^{\sigma-1} e^{-t \arg(-z)}.$

I can easily bound $|z|^{\sigma-1}$ on $C_n'$: $|z| \leq 100 n$ there, so $|z|^{\sigma-1} \leq 100^{\sigma-1} n^{\sigma-1}.$

The exponential factor however is giving me a hard time. For some choices of $z \in C_n'$ it can be $e^{(2n+1) \pi \cdot \frac{ \pi}{2}}$, which grows way too quickly.

Is the statement in the book true? And if so how can I modify proof in order to see that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$s = \sigma + it$ is fixed. When $z$ traverses the contour $C_n'$, the argument is constrained between $-\pi$ and $\pi$, therefore, you have the bound

$$\lvert (-z)^s\rvert = \lvert z\rvert^{\sigma-1} \cdot e^{-t\cdot \arg (-z)} \leqslant e^{\pi \lvert t\rvert}\cdot \lvert z\rvert^{\sigma-1} \leqslant e^{\pi \lvert t\rvert}\cdot (20n)^{\sigma-1}.$$

Comment: Thanks Daniel. For some reason I thought the $t$ was the imaginary part of $z$...

Comment: @user1337 I can imagine the reason: "we assume that the square part lies on the lines $t = \pm(2n+1)\pi$ and $\sigma = \pm(2n+1)\pi$." As great as Ahlfors' book is, his exposition is not always as clear as one would wish. (And why didn't I receive a notification of your comment? Hmm, it's in the inbox, must have come at the same time as another and I missed it.)